# ArrayFormula with TextJoin of a row of columns

Tags: google-sheets, split, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a table as follows:

[image: data table]

I would like to use the following formula `=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, Data!B2:C2),",")` with ArrayFormula, but I am not sure how I should adapt B2:C2 to work with the function.

Expected output (result of dragging formula down):
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the Ampersand Operator (&) Instead

The function `TEXTJOIN()` does not work with `ARRAYFORMULA()`. Instead, you may use the `Ampersand Operator (&)` expression to join the texts together. In your case, you may use the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(split(arrayformula(B2:B7 & "," & C2:C7),","))
```

### Sample Output

Based from the output below, your desired result was met.

[image: Output]

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: This works thank you! I think I was initially trying to figure it out using Ampersand but it's that double ARRAYFORMULA that I was missing. Well, now I am going to try and figure out how to adapt it to my actual design scenario which I created a separate question for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328248/how-to-skip-row-for-user-input-using-formula-i-e-arrayformula

Comment: as per the design requirement of my other post, is it possible to modify this equation such that it works with 2 horizontally merged cells?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I noticed that another community member has already answered your other question. With respect to modifying the contents of 2 horizontally merged cells, I think using google sheets formula would be challenging since only one cell in the merged cell would contain the data (i.e. in a merged cell of A1:B1, A1 will contain the data while B1 remains blank even if both cells are merged). Hence, I would probably recommend using Google Apps Script to address your new issue since it would be more practical (in my opinion).