# How to skip row for user input using formula?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Given the following table:

[image: data table]

I was able to find a formula that adds a blank row after each row for the 'Track Name' column, which allowed me to populate the new table (see expected output) correctly with ArrayFormula into merged cells.

`={"Track Name";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ROW(Data!A2:A),COUNTA(Data!A2:A)*2-1,1), {IF(LEN(Data!A2:A),ROW(Data!A1:A)*2,),Data!A2:A},{2},FALSE)," "))}`

Now, is it possible to then use ArrayFormula to retrieve the artists & features while skipping rows to allow for user input?

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

I could probably set this up using a script, but if I can avoid that then I think that'd be better...

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(array_constrain(row(A2:A),COUNTA(A2:A)*2-1,1),{if(len(A2:A),row(A1:A)*2,),ArrayFormula(split(ArrayFormula(B2:B & "," & C2:C),","))},{2,3,4,5},false)," "))
```

**Result:**
[image]

For the merged cells for the Track Name column I'm assuming you've formatted this manually.

To explain this I've used this formula from the reference link:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(array_constrain(row(A2:A),COUNTA(A2:A)*2-1,1),
{if(len(A2:A),row(A1:A)*2,),B2:C)},{2,3},false)," "))
```

I replaced the range `B2:C` with the formula from this post [ArrayFormula with TextJoin of a row of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328055/arrayformula-with-textjoin-of-a-row-of-columns) to join columns B and C and split them to multiple columns. I also changed the `{2,3}` to `{2,3,4,5}` (you need to change this if you are expecting more columns).

**NOTE:** This does not work for merged cells it is only displaying the value on the left cell if you have 2 horizontally merged cells.

Please see the reference link below if you need more information on the formula used.

**Reference:**

- Refer to this link for more detailed explanation: [Insert Blank Rows](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/insert-blank-rows-using-a-formula-in-google-sheets/)

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or if you have other questions.

Comment: Yeah this'll work, thanks. I'll probably have to settle with redesigning the table such that I don't need 2 horizontally merged cells. Now for the second part of my question, is it possible to allow users to input data to those skipped rows without causing issues? I know that ArrayFormula errors out normally with "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data..." if I were to attempt this.

Comment: Or perhaps there's a design of the expected output table that completely avoids the need  for merged cells and formulas that skip rows, but still presents the same data and allows for user input that doesn't intersect with ARRAYFORMULA.

Comment: This was my idea originally, but it is one that ends up using a lot of columns and makes it harder to explain how exactly the input should correspond to each artist e.g. "for the first track, you have the artist 'bonjr' and corresponding inputs 50 and 69 while for the second track, you have two artists 'øneheart' and 'reidenshi' with input pairs (10, 30) and (20, 40) respectively." But the plus side of this design is that everything is much easier to handle when it comes to formulas/scripts: https://i.gyazo.com/08a1f26f49c908d099391dde04f3cb45.png

Comment: Or of course as I mentioned in the original post, I can probably use a script to populate the formulas instead, and that way I could keep the original design of the expected output table.

Comment: Ah sorry I have missed you mentioning about the user input. It is not possible using formula since you really can't insert blank rows using only formula, the way this formula works is it returns space as string (" ") making it seem like skipping row. Yes you can only use script for this. Let me know if you need help with the script.